# Regex to see if video in ffmpeg output

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text string:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video
```

How would I do the following regex:

```
Stream <some text>: Video
```

Something like:

```
r'Stream \: Video'
```

Comment: so whats the problem ?

Comment: Basically I want to add a `.+` in the middle part, between "Stream" and "Video". How would I do that?

Comment: i add answer do you want that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just add it between them : `Stream.+Video`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qH0fL3/1)